# index a dataframe, create two lists one with sample and compare them

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames that look like this:

```
>df.A
NAME    pvalues    index
A       0.9        1
B       0.8        2
C       0.7        3
D       0.6        4
E       0.5        5
F       0.4        6
G       0.3        7
H       0.2        8
I       0.1        9

>df.B
NAME    VALUE      index
B       100        1
G       99         2
H       98         3
C       97         4
D       96         5
F       95         6
A       94         7
I       93         8
E       92         9
```

I want to sample elements from `df.A` a number of times (e.g. 100) selecting each time 4 elements and then to look which indexes of the `df.B` match these new data.frames, and at the end sum the index of these new data.frames.

My approach is the following;

```
res = list(data.frame())
for (i in 1:100){
res[[i]] = as.data.frame(sample(df.A$NAME, 4))
names(res[[i]]) <- 'NAME'
 }

func <- function(x,y){merge(x, y, by.x=names(x)[1], by.y=names(y)[1])}
rand <- lapply(res, func, df.B)
sum.random = sapply(rand, function(x) sum(x$index))
```

Both `data.frames` are a summary of my real data (13000 rows and 4 columns), therefore, speed of the process will be important. My current approach takes a long time, I think because of the `merge` step.

I've also tried with `data.table`

```
dt = data.table(df.B, key='NAME')
fn = function(x){dt[x]};
rand2 = lapply(res, func)
```

but it is also two slow,

Any ideas for improving the code? Sure I'm missing something obvious

Thanks

Comment: The sampled index will always match with df2 since the index of df1 is same as index of df2. There should be unique index in df2, otherwise it doesn't make sense to solve this problem (i.e. which is not in df1).

Comment: What I want to do is sampling df1 in a random way, retrieving different `NAME` and then interrogate which index these `NAME` has in df2. For example, name `A` is 1 in df1 but 7 in df2

Comment: and then you want the sum of these index, right?Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes @Metrics, that is right, any ideas?

Comment: I have posted the answer.You can check that

Comment: It's still not clear if names are unique. If they are, you could simply sample `df.B`.

Comment: Not, names are not unique @Roland, I have tried your approach and it works but with 10000 sampling is quite slow, perhaps trying a loop with 10 samplings of 1000?

Comment: The problem are probably the 10000 calls to `sample`. From your description I don't see a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
n.samp <- 4
n <- 100 

samp.names <- replicate(n, sample(df.A$NAME, n.samp))
library(data.table)
DT.B <- as.data.table(df.B)
setkey(DT.B, NAME)
tmp <- DT.B[c(samp.names),]
tmp[, grp := rep(seq_len(n), each=n.samp) ]
sum.random <- tmp[,sum(index), by=grp]$V1
```

You didn't make it clear why you can't sample `df.B` directly. Are names not unique? If that's the case, you could use this:

```
samp.names <- data.table(NAME=c(samp.names), 
                         grp = rep(seq_len(n), each=n.samp), key="NAME")
tmp <- DT.B[samp.names, all=TRUE]
tmp[,sum(index, na.rm=TRUE), by=grp]$V1
```

Comment: could you explain in a little detail the first line `samp.names <- data.table(NAME=c(samp.names), 
                         grp = rep(seq_len(n), each=n.samp), key="NAME")`, many thanks

Comment: This prepares a data.table for joining with DT.B. If `NAME`s are not unique, we need to create the grouping variable before the join. And we need to set keys to join by.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach and you can avoid `for loop` in R: (I assume sample size=3)

```
Data preparation
mydf1<-list(df1)
mydf1a<-rep(mydf1,100)
mydf2<-list(df2)
mydf2a<-rep(mydf2,100)
sampleno<-as.list(1:100)
```

**Sampling**

```
    set.seed(1)
kk<-Map(function(x) x[sample(1:nrow(x),3,replace=FALSE),], mydf1a)
ll<-Map(function(x,y,z)cbind(sampleno=z,mysum=sum(x[which(x[,1] %in% y[,1]),3])),kk,mydf2a,sampleno)
     myresult<-data.frame(do.call(rbind,ll))
 head(myresult)
  sampleno mysum
1        1    17
2        2    18
3        3    20
4        4    11
5        5    17
6        6    18
```